# Set expiration for grafana service account tokens through HTTP API

Tags: rest, curl, grafana, access-token

I'm trying to set expiration for grafana service account token through API, but I'm unaware of the correct key or value that needs to passed as part of body.

I tried set of ways to set expiration but I was out of luck.
Please help with the correct key and value format to be used to set the expiration.

Note : Token is created with no expiry always.
I have also set `token_expiration_day_limit` to 365 days.
I'm also able to create tokens with expiry from grafana UI.

Below are the different ways i tried

```
curl -X POST --insecure -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{
  "name": "grafana16",
  "expiration": "2023-08-23T10:31:02Z"
}' https://url
curl -X POST --insecure -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{
  "name": "grafana16",
  "expiration": "30d"
}' https://url


#epoch time
curl -X POST --insecure -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{
  "name": "grafana16",
  "expiration": "1692537131"
}' https://url

curl -X POST --insecure -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{
  "name": "grafana16",
  "expiration": "2023-08-21"
}' https://url
```

Tried the above ways by giving key as "expires", "time-to-live"

Answer (score 0):

Grafana's Service Account API doc is lacking this information. But I found a way to set the expiration date on the deprecated API key doc.
You have to set the field "secondsToLive" in the request body of the POST request to the SA's token endpoint.

Example:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:3000/api/serviceaccounts/1/tokens' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "name": "example-sa",
    "secondsToLive": 3600
}'
```

At the UI, it will show 'Expires in 1 day', but getting the token at the HTTP API will show that it will expire in 1 hour.